# Packages apt-get vs brew?

Tags: macos, ubuntu

Im trying to get something running in a lab, and I need to install a whole bunch of packages to compile the code:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk2.0-dev libwxgtk3.0-dev libwx-perl libmodule-build-perl git cpanminus libextutils-cppguess-perl libboost-all-dev libxmu-dev liblocal-lib-perl wx-common libopengl-perl libwx-glcanvas-perl libtbb-dev libxmu-dev freeglut3-dev libwxgtk-media3.0-dev libboost-thread-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libextutils-makemaker-cpanfile-perl
```

The problem is, I'm working on a Mac; So I only have brew available - and the package names are not equivalent.

Am I trying to do something dumb and impossible, or is there a way to cross reference those apt-get packages to ones available in brew and install those so I can build the app?

For added context, its a modified "slicer" application for generating files that a 3d printer uses to make parts. I could fire up an ubuntu VM and use apt-get, but I'm on an M1 mac at the moment and recompiling experimental QEMU code just so I can fire up an ubuntu VM takes me way more out of my depth than I already am... I'm running brew on a duplicated, rosetta emulation forced terminal.

Comment: Did you consider to install the Perl modules with cpanminus (`cpanm`)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way to automatically figure out whether a corresponding Homebrew package exists for each of these packages, no. But you can probably guess the majority, and manually figure out the rest. Each Debian package has a link to the upstream sources, and a home page if one exists, from which you can often find links to packages for other architectures, etc.

From the [Debian package search page](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) you can search e.g. for [the `libxmu-dev` package](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libxmu-dev&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all), and discover the [corresponding package page for Buster (the current stable Debian release)](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libxmu-dev), which in turn has links to the upstream repo, etc. But this is an X11 package, so it's not straightforwardly compatible with macOS, which uses an entirely different GUI architecture.